# Laravel: how to show accessor in a groupBy query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model like this in `Ticket.php` that contains a mutator called `getAssigneeFullNameFormattedAttribute()`.
I append the mutator attribute to the model response as `assignee_full_name_formatted`. Here the model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ticket extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['assignee_full_name_formatted'];
    protected $hidden = ['assignee'];

    /**
     * Get the assignee of the support ticket.
     */
    public function assignee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    /**
     * Get the assignee of the ticket formatted.
     *
     * @return null | string
     */
    public function getAssigneeFullNameFormattedAttribute()
    {
        $person = $this->assignee;
        return $this->getShortFullName($person);
    }

    ...

    /**
     *
     * @param  string  $person
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getShortFullName($person)
    {
        ...
        return $full_name_formatted;
    }
}
```

And in the controller `TicketController.php` I am using query like this for returning the unique values from an attribute (`assignee_name`) of the model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Ticket;

class TicketController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of 'assignee_name's.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getFieldUniqueRecords(Ticket $tickets, Request $request)
    {
        $unique_records = $tickets->select('assignee_name')
            ->groupBy('assignee_name')
            ->paginate($pagination_results_per_page);
        return $unique_records;
    }
}
```

The output however is not displaying the value in the accessor `assignee_full_name_formatted`:

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "assignee_name": "joe@example.com",
            "assignee_full_name_formatted": null,
            ...
        },
        ...
}
```

If how can I could I make sure the value in the accessor `assignee_full_name_formatted` is displayed and not `null`?

Thanks

Comment: In Laravel Eloquent, it is not possible to directly use accessors and mutators in a groupBy query. Accessors and mutators are methods that are executed after the data is retrieved from the database or before it is inserted into the database, respectively. They are not part of the underlying database structure.